How to group a prometheus metric by day?
I'm using Prometheus and Grafana, and I'd like to create a graph for the total number of HTTP requests served by day.
Our application exposes the current count, and therefore, I'm using this code to count the number of requests in the last 24hours.
sum(sum_over_time(http_server_requests_seconds_count{}[24h]))

My need is now to look into the last x days and group by day instead of counting the latest 24 hours.


You are doing metrics wrong, or rather not in a "Prometheus way". Metric you show should be http_server_requests_total, and it should be counter (as in total number of requests since app/server restart).



Even with that in mind your query ( assuming it gets you expected results) should work. You need to simply set step to 1d, and grafana will align request range with day ends, iirc.


http_server_requests_total seems not to be exposed by Spring Boot

Oh, sorry, I misunderstood what is going on. If this is spring's metrics, your query is incorrect. It should be sum(increase(http_server_requests_seconds_count[24h])) (http_server_requests_seconds_count behaves as counter, even though its part of histogram).
